# Why DOMDocument load isn't working online?

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

I have this simple code retrieving data from an xml/rss feed url online. If i go to the path of the feed i can see it and it's working. The code works locally, using a local xml. When i put it online, though, the echo return nothing.

```
$xmldom = new DOMDocument();
$xmldom->load("url_path");
$nodo = $xmldom->getElementsByTagName("item");
echo $nodo;
```

Even an 
    echo $xmldom->load("url_path");
return nothing (nor true nor false: nothing, i.e. empty string). Now why is this happening? Some server setting i can check? Some test i can run to check what is the problem? 
There's even no error in console shown (firebug).

Comment: Are you seeing a blank page? Could be you're missing the xml extension on the server and the settings are suppressing the error message.

Comment: Cann't you please use $feed_xml = simplexml_load_file('url_path');
$nodo=$feed_xml->Row;

Comment: @DaSourcerer yes blank page. What do you mean by missing the xml extension? How can i chack? Shashank  i tried, but no luck. $feed_xml is blank

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene try `<pre><?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?></pre>`. That should give you a pretty good idea about which extensions are installed on the server. It sounds *very much* like the xml one isn't installed.

Comment: ....
    [38] => wddx
    [39] => xml
    [40] => xmlreader
    [41] => xmlrpc
    [42] => xmlwriter
    [43] => xsl
    [44] => zip
    [45] => cgi-fcgi
    [46] => mhash

So the problem is not that? @DaSourcerer

Comment: Ok, so the problem lies obviously elsewhere ... Try to set `error_reporting(-1);` in the beginning of your script and look for error messages.

Comment: I realized now that the xml is in the same directory of the php file. (code not mine, helping a friend) So, using as url_path simply the name of the xml works like a charm... The problem was giving a full url http://some_url.com/page.php. Thank you anyway :)